# Loop does not work to print alphabets

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am using emu8086 assembler and I am new in assembly language. I want to print all A-Z alphabets in yellow color with black background. My loop is not working. It keeps running and only B alphabet is showing.
Can someone please help me? Here is my code:

```
include emu8086.inc
ORG 100h
MOV AX,0B800h
MOV DS,AX
MOV CX,26
ALPHABETS:
MOV CL,41h
ADD CX,1
MOV CH,00001110b
MOV BX,0x0000
MOV [BX],CX
loop ALPHABETS
RET
```

Comment: Try walking thru it in your head: You set cl to 41h, you add 1, you write it, then you loop back to ALPHABETS where you....

Comment: @DavidWohlferd
`include emu8086.inc    
ORG 100h`
`MOV AX,0B800H`
`MOV DS,AX`
`MOV CX,25`
`MOV AH,2`
`MOV DL,65`
`alpha:`
`INT 21h`
`INC DL`
`MOV DH,00001110b`
`;ADD DH,1`
`MOV BX,0x0000`
`MOV [BX],DX`
 `loop alpha`
`RET`
now its print but **A** turns into **Z** at the end and yellow colour applies only on **Z** which was **A** in the starting. Where i am wrong please let me know

Comment: Under DOS, there were 2 ways to display things: 1) Write directly to video memory at 0B800h or 2) Use DOS (or BIOS) interrupts such as `int 21h`.  Your new code is trying to do both, which makes it hard to read.  I don't think `int 21h` has any way to output attributes (colors).  If that's important, you would either need to write both the character and its attribute to memory (method 1), or use [`int 10h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H) with AH=09h.

Comment: Seeing the problem with a debugger should have been trivial, as you watch the value of CX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has 2 problems:

- You use the `CX` register for both the loop counter and the character that you want to display.
- You forget to update the address in the `BX` register and so everything gets displayed on top of each other.

First solution using `CX` as a loop counter:

```
include emu8086.inc
ORG 100h
    MOV     AX, 0B800h
    MOV     DS, AX
    mov     al, "A"       ;First character
    mov     ah, 00001110b ;YellowOnBlack
    mov     bx, 0         ;Address in video RAM
    mov     cx, 26
ALPHABETS:
    mov     [bx], ax
    inc     al            ;Next character
    add     bx, 2         ;Next address
    loop    ALPHABETS
    RET
```

Second solution using the character code itself as a loop counter:

```
include emu8086.inc
ORG 100h
    MOV     AX, 0B800h
    MOV     DS, AX
    mov     al, "A"       ;First character
    mov     ah, 00001110b ;YellowOnBlack
    mov     bx, 0         ;Address in video RAM
ALPHABETS:
    mov     [bx], ax
    inc     al            ;Next character
    add     bx, 2         ;Next address
    cmp     al, "Z"
    jbe     ALPHABETS
    RET
```